# Click variables are empty

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track all outbound links that contains the `target=_blank`, and after many hours of testing I realized that each click variables (in the debug mode) seems to be empty. I guess this is because there's a `span` element within the `anchor`. On some clicks the variables contain the full URL and attributes etc, but most of the time they don't - and there doesn't seem to be any constistency in this behavior.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong here? Thanks!

DOM for the link:

```
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" target="_blank" role="button">
                        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">Se priset</span>
        </span>
                    </a>
        </div>
```

[image: GTM Click Variables]

Comment: Could you please add the relevant part of the HTML code.

Comment: Sorry. Just added now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, please see my suggestion below

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are using click trigger for all elements, which captures the exact element clicked, which is the `span.elementor-button-text`

You should use just "Click - Just links" type of trigger, and specify the links you would like to track. This will ensure, that the clicked element is the a tag, regardless of its child elements, that can get clicked.

You can set your trigger to capture only links with `target=_blank` attribute as {{Click Element}} matches CSS selector `a[target="_blank"]`

E.g.
[image]

EDIT:

Based on your relevant code part, the Link Click event should look like this:
[image]

Comment: I tried this but now the Click event isn't triggered at all.

Comment: You should get a Link Click event, which you can use for firing tags. Please see my edit, where I have reused your code.

Comment: I don't get a Link Click event either.

Comment: Do you know what the issue can @kgrg?

Comment: Sorry, no exact ideas at this point. Do you maybe have other event listeners related to this element or its children, which could prevent the click event to be triggered?